# Data becoming 19 KB in Parquet from 2 KB in JSON

Tags: parquet

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.parquet</groupId>
            <artifactId>parquet-avro</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

AVRO/Schema:
changesInPII and payload are blob fields encrypted with custom tool.My parquet file becoming almost 9 times than original size of 2 KB is strange behaviour that I did not expect.Does Parquet supports blob formats and is it recommended to store it inside string field.I

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "ProfileAuditSchema",
  "doc": "Profile Audit Records",
  "fields":
  [{
    "name": "profileId",
    "type": "string"
  },
    {
      "name": "entityType",
      "type": "string"

    },
    {
      "name": "entityId",
      "type": "string"

    },
    {
      "name": "changesInPII",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "changesInNonPII",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "createdBy",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "createdAt",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "version",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "payload",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "operation",
      "type": "string"
    }

  ]
}
```